# Entity - one to one relationships

Tags: entity

So I have 2 tables.  Labor and Range.

```
Labor
LaborID

Range
RangeID
LaborID
```

Range has a foreign key constraint for LaborID.  The constraint is unique, and I've added a unique index on the LaborID to complete the 1 to 1 relationship.

My problem is, when adding these tables to my entity object, it shows the relationship as 1 to Many.  I added these tables to a diagram in SQL Server, and they clearly have a 1 to 1 relationship.  What am I missing here?  If I manually change the entity table's properties to 1 --> 0..1 { which it is }, then it errors out.

I don't want a 1 to many relationship.  Each labor will have one and only one range.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Labor
{
    [Key]
    public int LaborID {get;set;}
}

public class Range
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Labor")]
    public int RangeID {get;set;}
    public virtual Labor Labor {get;set;}
}
```

You dont need create a new ID for "RANGE CLASS" use the same properity to be the ID and FOREIGN KEY